# Visual Basic Regex but no double quotes

Tags: regex, vb.net

i'm using regex to get some information from a website, i have this code:

```
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.startkabel.nl/zoeken/index.php?zoek=" & TextBox1.Text)

Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse

Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

Dim startpagina As String = sr.ReadToEnd

Dim sp As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<a href=http://games.startkabel.nl>games.startkabel.nl</a></td>")

Dim matches As MatchCollection = sp.Matches(startpagina)


For Each itemcode As Match In matches    
    ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Value.Split("""").GetValue(0))    
Next
```

but `<a href=http://games.startkabel.nl>games.startkabel.nl</a></td>` doesn't have `""` so the listbox shows the whole code while I only need this part

```
games.startkabel.nl
```

i already tried to change the code to this:

```
"<a href=""http://games.startkabel.nl"">""games.startkabel.nl""</a></td>"
```

but then it doesn't show any result.

Can someone help me with this problem?

(sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to retrieve the hyperlink URL or the hyperlink name?

```
itemcode.Value.Split("="c, "<"c, ">"c).GetValue(2)
```

will return the URL "http://games.startkabel.nl"

```
itemcode.Value.Split("="c, "<"c, ">"c).GetValue(3)
```

will return the hyperlink name "games.startkabel.nl"